# Qiwi is not a constructor (node-qiwi-api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

При добавлении var Wallet = new Qiwi(`token`); появляется ошибка Qiwi is not a constructor как решить данную проблему?

```
var Qiwi = require('node-qiwi-api').Qiwi;
var Wallet = new Qiwi('тут ввожу qiwi token');
```

Comment: ````var Wallet = Qiwi('тут ввожу qiwi token');```` убираем new

Comment: @lijil тогда выходит Qiwi is not a function

Comment: стоит посмотреть тогда что есть Qiwi ````console.log(Qiwi)````, подозреваю undefined

Comment: гм, в документации `node-qiwi-api`, вроде как, нет ничего о `Qiwi` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qiwi-api

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь использовать пример из старой документации с новой версией библиотеки. Пожалуйста, проверьте версию пакета в своем package.json и ознакомьтесь с документацией для вашей версией на [странице пакета](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qiwi-api).

Вы также можете задать вопросы в разделе [issues](https://github.com/InsightAppDev/node-qiwi-api) репозитория на github.